# printing a float with fixed size of 0

Tags: php, floating-point, number-formatting

Consider i have this number:

```
0.012
0.1
0.04
0.0011
```

i need them to have always 4 digits after .

Example:

```
0.0120
0.1000
0.0400
0.0011
```

Should i use printf?

%f1.4?

Comment: printf does exactly what you want. alternatively you could use number_format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%.4f` is what you're looking for.

The following will output the number to standard output or the web page:

```
printf("%.4f", $number);
```

Or if you want to dump it to a string:

```
$str = sprintf("%.4f", $number);
```